# How to bind a new datatable to a gridview which already has an old datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a gridview which is bound to a datatable at runtime. According to the user selection, the datatable's columns can change and then I need to bind the datatable to the same gridview. If the user does so, the system crashes because gridview looks for the same column names.

How can I clean all the gridview and bind a new datatable again and again?

this is how I bind data. everytime column names are changing

```
DataTable result = dt_to_result_bolge_kiyaslama(dt);
gv_kiyaslama.DataSource = result;
gv_kiyaslama.DataBind();
```

Comment: The easiest would just be to re initialize the gridview or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Are you using auto-generated columns in your gridview, or no?

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for how to re-genarate Grid View columns at run time. This CodeProject.com article might be the ticket: [How to create columns dynamically in a grid view](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13461/how-to-create-columns-dynamically-in-a-grid-view).

Some sample ASP Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns />
</asp:GridView>
```

And a sample C# method:

```
public void RegenerateColumns(GridView grid, DataTable data, IDictionary<string, string> columnText)
{
    grid.Columns.Clear();

    foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
    {
        grid.Columns.Add(new BoundField()
        {
            DataField = col.ColumnName,
            HeaderText = columnText.ContainsKey(col.ColumnName)
                ? columnText[col.ColumnName]
                : col.ColumnName
        });
    }
}
```

Now to use:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(...); // add "NAME" column
table.Columns.Add(...); // add "DESCRIPTION" column

// Create mapping of column names to text visible to the user
Dictionary<string, string> cols = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "NAME", "Name" },
    { "DESCRIPTION", "Description" }
};

// Call method:
RegenerateColumns(MyGrid, table, cols);

// Rebind the data to the grid
MyGrid.DataSource = table;
MyGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: this explains to how to bind grid dynamically. I can do that succesfully, but if I change the column name and bind it again to the same grid, then it crashes because it looks for the old column names

Comment: That article does explain what you want. I'll update my answer.

Comment: that is not the good way. I am looking forward to find a function like clear()

Comment: There is a `clear` function: `GridView.Columns.Clear()` -- It clears the columns on the grid.

Comment: I know but if I do clear(), It doesnt accept the second datatable's columns

Comment: Did you read the blog post I linked to, or view the code example I posted? After clearing the columns, you must programmatically create them again.